# DB2 query based on condition from same table

Tags: sql, db2

I'm facing problem when trying to extract row that based on condition from another row. 
Sample table:

```
GroupID         |    Name       |    Salary    |    Car

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9009           |    Isaac      |   10,000     |   Honda
 9009           |    Ricky      |              |   Nissan
 9080           |    Patrick    |   20,000     |   Ferrari
 9080           |    Susan      |   30,000     |   Nissan
```

Questions:
How should I query if I want to extract data like this:

```
GroupID         |    Name       |    Salary    |    Car

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9009           |    Isaac      |   10,000     |   Honda
 9080           |    Patrick    |   20,000     |   Ferrari
```

based on condition `car = Nissan`?

Comment: Based on above table data and your *logic* what is your expected results should?

Comment: what is expected result please write it in tabular format, so that its more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've updated my question to clear any doubts.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please see if it fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT GroupID, Name, Salary, Car
  FROM tableName
 WHERE GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID
                     FROM tableName
                    WHERE Car = 'Nissan') -- << Your input
   AND car <> 'Nissan'
```

Read more about subqueries **[here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z.doc.intro/db2z_subqueries.html)**.

Comment: omg it works. I tried to use CASE as my subquery which doesnt returned me the expected result and so I thought subquery wont work. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable where Car <> 'Nissan';
```

Would seem to do what you asked for.
You need to be more explicit about what you are trying to achieve here.